# How to pass a list ,integer,strings as an arguments of function from python to C

Tags: python, c

I have a python code as mentioned below ,its calling a "C" function trans implemenetd as python extension .How to extract integer,string,list all different type of argument together  at C code ?
Below code is not working to extract list as an argument .Code below is just a sample code which will give an idea about the question I have .it's not complete code .

Test.py

```
def tpp:  
    value =0455455  
    name ='go'  
    parameter =[0,0,0]  
    parameter[0] ='hello'
    parameter[1] ='helloworld'        
    trans(value =value, name =name ,parameter =parameter)
```

trans.c

```
  static Pyobject mod_trans(Pyobject *self, Pyobject *args ,Pyobject *keyargs)  
   {    
     char name ;  
     int value ;  
     char* parameter;  
     static char *kwlist[] ={"value", "name", "parameter")  
     if(!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args,keyargs, "si|items",kwlist,&name,&value,
         &parameter)  
      return NULL;


    }
```

Comment: Your code also doesn't compile at all...can you post your *real* code?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in a list and expecting a string out (`char *`); this won't work. Lists can only converted to `PyObject *`. Therefore, you should use

```
PyObject *parameter;
...
if(!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "is|O", kwlist, &name, &value, &parameter))
```

If you want to enforce that the object is a list, use

```
PyObject *parameter;
...
if(!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "is|O!", kwlist, &name, &value, &PyList_Type, &parameter))
```

Comment: Hi nneonneo ,I have added the printf statements in my code ,but I how can i print the list value ? could you please let me know if i used PyObject *parameter

Comment: You stuck the `printf` after a `return NULL;`...perhaps you would be better served by a C refresher course?

Comment: @jaysh By iterating over the list elements, verifying that they are indeed numeric, converting them to numbers and outputting them.

Comment: I can't iterate through the list directly as i need to know the length of list .I got one API Pysequence_size(parameter) to get the length

Comment: Uh, that *does* gives you the length of the list. What's the problem here? If you just want to print it out like Python's `repr`, consider using `PyObject_Repr`.

Comment: I am new in Python C-API coding

Comment: From your post, it seems you are new to C...is this true?

Comment: @jaysh Depending on your ability in Python - you may find that all this that you're trying to do (and looking at previous posts) could more easily be achieved using `Cython` - If you're new to Python *and* C, you've probably not chosen the best of things to be working on as a starter project ;)

Comment: Well, it's less "not wanting to share code", and more "suggesting alternative courses of action so you aren't going to continue needing help".

Comment: My code is working gone through multiples API -PySequence_Fast_GET_ITEM helps me to get the list values:-)